# How to get name or id of the input?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have few  fields which have different id's and name's. I have specified a common class name to those fields for eg. class="selectajax".

I want to get the select's id="xxx" or name="xyz" value whenever it gets focus via jquery and I want to do this because i'm using select2 and whenever something is typed for searching via ajax, I want to get the name of the field so I can pass it to the ajax request.

So far I have this code but its producing error:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectajax').select2({
        var name1 = $(this).attr("name");
        alert(name1);

        ajax: {
            url: 'ajax-products.php',
            data: function(params) {
                var query = {
                    search: params.term,
                    type: 'public'
                }

                // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&type=public
                return query;
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need the name or id ? What do you want to achieve by getting that when an element gets focused ?

Comment: I will then send that id or name in the ajax request to get the relevant data and populate the select2 dropdown.